# Sequelize returns incorrect result when adding `offset` and `limit`

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I know that this question can be duplicate to some of the questions out there, but no matter what way I try there is always something wrong.

The problem is that as soon as I add `limit` and `offset` to Sequelize model  `findAll()`, it starts returning wrong/not-expected results.

Expected: For a query that results in `4277` rows normally, with a `limit` of `10` and the page `428`, should return `7` items.

Actual: The above described expectation will return `10` rows.

- By removing all the `includes` it actually starts returning the correct/expected results.
- If i disable the `subQuery` I get an error: `(unrelevant, I think...)`

```
ppt-api-1         |   original: Error: Duplicate column name 'UserId'
ppt-api-1         |       at Packet.asError (/usr/src/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
ppt-api-1         |       at Query.execute (/usr/src/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
ppt-api-1         |       at Connection.handlePacket (/usr/src/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:456:32)
ppt-api-1         |       at PacketParser.onPacket (/usr/src/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:85:12)
ppt-api-1         |       at PacketParser.executeStart (/usr/src/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
ppt-api-1         |       at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:92:25)
ppt-api-1         |       at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
ppt-api-1         |       at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
ppt-api-1         |       at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
ppt-api-1         |       at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10) {
ppt-api-1         |     code: 'ER_DUP_FIELDNAME',
ppt-api-1         |     errno: 1060,
ppt-api-1         |     sqlState: '42S21',
ppt-api-1         |     sqlMessage: "Duplicate column name 'UserId'",
```

Workaround: The only way I could fix this is to fetch without `limit` and `offset` and then `slice(offset, offset + limit)` the whole array of rows. Which is not that good of an idea when I am dealing with about `16000` rows.

The action in controller:

```
static async index(req: IPttRequest, res: Response) {
    const rows = parseInt((req.query.rows || 10) as string)
    const page = parseInt((req.query.page || 1) as string)
    const order = (req.query.order || 'id,desc') as string

    const orderObject = order.split(',') as OrderItem
    const orderByRelation = (orderObject as string[])[0].includes(':')
    let orderRelation = ''

    if (orderByRelation) {
      orderRelation = (orderObject as string[])[0].split(':')[0] as string
      ;(orderObject as string[])[0] = (orderObject as string[])[0].split(':')[1]
      if (orderRelation === 'property')
        (orderObject as string[]).unshift(EntityMapperSingular.PROPERTY)
    }

    console.log('==========================', orderObject)

    let whereObject = {}
    if (req.currentUser?.isContractor()) {
      const orderIdsFromAgreements = (
        await OrderAgreement.findAll({
          where: {
            [Op.or]: [
              { clientId: req.currentUser?.getCompany()?.id },
              { contractorId: req.currentUser?.getCompany()?.id }
            ]
          }
        })
      ).map((orderAgreement) => orderAgreement.id)

      whereObject = {
        where: {
          [Op.or]: [
            { userId: req.currentUser?.id },
            { companyId: req.currentUser?.getCompany()?.id },
            { id: { [Op.in]: orderIdsFromAgreements } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }

    const findObject: Omit<
      FindOptions<InferAttributes<OrderDocument, { omit: 'user' | 'company' }>>,
      'group'
    > = { ...whereObject }

    const count = await Order.count(findObject)

    findObject.order = [orderObject]
    findObject.offset = (page - 1) * rows
    findObject.limit = rows
    findObject.include = [
      { model: User, as: EntityMapperSingular.USER },
      { model: Company, as: EntityMapperSingular.COMPANY },
      {
        model: Inspection,
        as: EntityMapperSingular.INSPECTION,
        include: [
          {
            model: PhotoDocumentation,
            as: EntityMapperSingular.PHOTO_DOCUMENTATION
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        model: Property,
        as: EntityMapperSingular.PROPERTY,
        include: [
          {
            model: Address,
            as: EntityMapperSingular.ADDRESS
          }
        ]
      },
      { model: Task, as: EntityMapperPlural.TASKS },
      {
        model: OrderAgreement,
        as: EntityMapperPlural.ORDERS_AGREEMENTS,
        include: [
          { model: Company, as: 'client', foreignKey: 'client_id' },
          { model: Company, as: 'contractor', foreignKey: 'contractor_id' }
        ]
      }
    ]
    findObject.subQuery = false

    console.log('<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', findObject.order)

    const orders = await Order.findAll(findObject)

    // const count = orders.length

    // const start = (page - 1) * rows
    // orders = orders.slice(start, start + rows)

    res.send({
      orders: OrderResource.collection<OrderDocument>(orders, OrderResource),
      meta: { totalRows: count, totalPages: Math.ceil(count / rows) }
    })
  }
```

The 5th to last lines of code that are commented out are the workaround that I explained.

This is the executed query, requesting the URL: `http://localhost:3000/api/orders?page=428&order=id,asc`

```
SELECT
    `Order`.`id`,
    `Order`.`user_id` AS `userId`,
    `Order`.`company_id` AS `companyId`,
    `Order`.`custom_id` AS `customId`,
    `Order`.`portfolio`,
    `Order`.`certification`,
    `Order`.`realty_condition` AS `realtyCondition`,
    `Order`.`status`,
    `Order`.`service`,
    `Order`.`stop_reason` AS `stopReason`,
    `Order`.`notes`,
    `Order`.`show_primary_client` AS `showPrimaryClient`,
    `Order`.`delivery_type` AS `deliveryType`,
    `Order`.`delivery_binding` AS `deliveryBinding`,
    `Order`.`delivery_quantity` AS `deliveryQuantity`,
    `Order`.`purchase_price_financing` AS `purchasePriceFinancing`,
    `Order`.`created_at` AS `createdAt`,
    `Order`.`updated_at` AS `updatedAt`,
    `Order`.`user_id` AS `UserId`,
    `Order`.`company_id` AS `CompanyId`,
    `user`.`id` AS `user.id`,
    `user`.`first_name` AS `user.firstName`,
    `user`.`last_name` AS `user.lastName`,
    `user`.`username` AS `user.username`,
    `user`.`email` AS `user.email`,
    `user`.`profile_picture` AS `user.profilePicture`,
    `user`.`phone` AS `user.phone`,
    `user`.`team` AS `user.team`,
    `user`.`project` AS `user.project`,
    `user`.`password` AS `user.password`,
    `user`.`gender` AS `user.gender`,
    `user`.`billing_rights` AS `user.billingRights`,
    `user`.`user_management_rights` AS `user.userManagementRights`,
    `user`.`visible` AS `user.visible`,
    `user`.`status` AS `user.status`,
    `user`.`module_rights` AS `user.moduleRights`,
    `user`.`password_updated_at` AS `user.passwordUpdatedAt`,
    `user`.`email_verified_at` AS `user.emailVerifiedAt`,
    `user`.`expires_at` AS `user.expiresAt`,
    `user`.`created_at` AS `user.createdAt`,
    `user`.`updated_at` AS `user.updatedAt`,
    `user`.`deleted_at` AS `user.deletedAt`,
    `user`.`company_id` AS `user.companyId`,
    `company`.`id` AS `company.id`,
    `company`.`reference` AS `company.reference`,
    `company`.`name` AS `company.name`,
    `company`.`addressee_1` AS `company.addressee_1`,
    `company`.`addressee_2` AS `company.addressee_2`,
    `company`.`api_name` AS `company.apiName`,
    `company`.`api_key` AS `company.apiKey`,
    `company`.`api_hash` AS `company.apiHash`,
    `company`.`visible` AS `company.visible`,
    `company`.`can_share_order` AS `company.canShareOrder`,
    `company`.`contract_signed_at` AS `company.contractSignedAt`,
    `company`.`created_at` AS `company.createdAt`,
    `company`.`updated_at` AS `company.updatedAt`,
    `company`.`deleted_at` AS `company.deletedAt`,
    `company`.`archived_at` AS `company.archivedAt`,
    `company`.`payment_type_id` AS `company.paymentTypeId`,
    `company`.`address_id` AS `company.addressId`,
    `company`.`payment_type_id` AS `company.PaymentTypeId`,
    `company`.`address_id` AS `company.AddressId`,
    `inspection`.`id` AS `inspection.id`,
    `inspection`.`order_id` AS `inspection.orderId`,
    `inspection`.`last_attempted_at` AS `inspection.lastAttemptedAt`,
    `inspection`.`next_attempt_at` AS `inspection.nextAttemptAt`,
    `inspection`.`started_at` AS `inspection.startedAt`,
    `inspection`.`duration` AS `inspection.duration`,
    `inspection`.`order_id` AS `inspection.order_id`,
    `inspection->photo_documentation`.`id` AS `inspection.photo_documentation.id`,
    `inspection->photo_documentation`.`inspection_id` AS `inspection.photo_documentation.inspectionId`,
    `inspection->photo_documentation`.`inspection_id` AS `inspection.photo_documentation.inspection_id`,
    `property`.`id` AS `property.id`,
    `property`.`order_id` AS `property.orderId`,
    `property`.`address_id` AS `property.addressId`,
    `property`.`object_type` AS `property.objectType`,
    `property`.`is_hired_out` AS `property.isHiredOut`,
    `property`.`is_divisioned` AS `property.isDivisioned`,
    `property`.`is_leasehold` AS `property.isLeasehold`,
    `property`.`is_managed` AS `property.isManaged`,
    `property`.`is_project` AS `property.isProject`,
    `property`.`has_value_relevant_land_register_rights` AS `property.hasValueRelevantLandRegisterRights`,
    `property`.`order_id` AS `property.order_id`,
    `property`.`address_id` AS `property.address_id`,
    `property`.`address_id` AS `property.AddressId`,
    `property->address`.`id` AS `property.address.id`,
    `property->address`.`addition` AS `property.address.addition`,
    `property->address`.`latitude` AS `property.address.latitude`,
    `property->address`.`longitude` AS `property.address.longitude`,
    `property->address`.`street_name` AS `property.address.streetName`,
    `property->address`.`street_number` AS `property.address.streetNumber`,
    `property->address`.`city_name` AS `property.address.cityName`,
    `property->address`.`postcode` AS `property.address.postcode`,
    `property->address`.`state` AS `property.address.state`,
    `property->address`.`country` AS `property.address.country`,
    `tasks`.`id` AS `tasks.id`,
    `tasks`.`company_id` AS `tasks.companyId`,
    `tasks`.`client_id` AS `tasks.clientId`,
    `tasks`.`title` AS `tasks.title`,
    `tasks`.`class` AS `tasks.class`,
    `tasks`.`address` AS `tasks.address`,
    `tasks`.`service` AS `tasks.service`,
    `tasks`.`object_type` AS `tasks.objectType`,
    `tasks`.`description` AS `tasks.description`,
    `tasks`.`link` AS `tasks.link`,
    `tasks`.`category` AS `tasks.category`,
    `tasks`.`priority` AS `tasks.priority`,
    `tasks->SelectedTask`.`id` AS `tasks.SelectedTask.id`,
    `tasks->SelectedTask`.`order_id` AS `tasks.SelectedTask.orderId`,
    `tasks->SelectedTask`.`task_id` AS `tasks.SelectedTask.taskId`,
    `tasks->SelectedTask`.`assignee_id` AS `tasks.SelectedTask.assigneeId`,
    `tasks->SelectedTask`.`deadline_at` AS `tasks.SelectedTask.deadlineAt`,
    `tasks->SelectedTask`.`priority` AS `tasks.SelectedTask.priority`,
    `tasks->SelectedTask`.`status` AS `tasks.SelectedTask.status`,
    `tasks->SelectedTask`.`order_id` AS `tasks.SelectedTask.order_id`,
    `tasks->SelectedTask`.`task_id` AS `tasks.SelectedTask.task_id`,
    `order_agreements`.`id` AS `order_agreements.id`,
    `order_agreements`.`order_id` AS `order_agreements.orderId`,
    `order_agreements`.`created_by` AS `order_agreements.createdBy`,
    `order_agreements`.`client_id` AS `order_agreements.clientId`,
    `order_agreements`.`contractor_id` AS `order_agreements.contractorId`,
    `order_agreements`.`is_active` AS `order_agreements.isActive`,
    `order_agreements`.`can_be_subcontracted` AS `order_agreements.canBeSubcontracted`,
    `order_agreements`.`status` AS `order_agreements.status`,
    `order_agreements`.`accepted_at` AS `order_agreements.acceptedAt`,
    `order_agreements`.`declined_at` AS `order_agreements.declinedAt`,
    `order_agreements`.`deadline_at` AS `order_agreements.deadlineAt`,
    `order_agreements`.`created_at` AS `order_agreements.createdAt`,
    `order_agreements`.`updated_at` AS `order_agreements.updatedAt`,
    `order_agreements`.`order_id` AS `order_agreements.order_id`,
    `order_agreements`.`client_id` AS `order_agreements.client_id`,
    `order_agreements`.`contractor_id` AS `order_agreements.contractor_id`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`id` AS `order_agreements.client.id`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`reference` AS `order_agreements.client.reference`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`name` AS `order_agreements.client.name`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`addressee_1` AS `order_agreements.client.addressee_1`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`addressee_2` AS `order_agreements.client.addressee_2`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`api_name` AS `order_agreements.client.apiName`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`api_key` AS `order_agreements.client.apiKey`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`api_hash` AS `order_agreements.client.apiHash`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`visible` AS `order_agreements.client.visible`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`can_share_order` AS `order_agreements.client.canShareOrder`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`contract_signed_at` AS `order_agreements.client.contractSignedAt`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`created_at` AS `order_agreements.client.createdAt`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`updated_at` AS `order_agreements.client.updatedAt`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`deleted_at` AS `order_agreements.client.deletedAt`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`archived_at` AS `order_agreements.client.archivedAt`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`payment_type_id` AS `order_agreements.client.paymentTypeId`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`address_id` AS `order_agreements.client.addressId`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`payment_type_id` AS `order_agreements.client.PaymentTypeId`,
    `order_agreements->client`.`address_id` AS `order_agreements.client.AddressId`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`id` AS `order_agreements.contractor.id`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`reference` AS `order_agreements.contractor.reference`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`name` AS `order_agreements.contractor.name`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`addressee_1` AS `order_agreements.contractor.addressee_1`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`addressee_2` AS `order_agreements.contractor.addressee_2`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`api_name` AS `order_agreements.contractor.apiName`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`api_key` AS `order_agreements.contractor.apiKey`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`api_hash` AS `order_agreements.contractor.apiHash`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`visible` AS `order_agreements.contractor.visible`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`can_share_order` AS `order_agreements.contractor.canShareOrder`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`contract_signed_at` AS `order_agreements.contractor.contractSignedAt`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`created_at` AS `order_agreements.contractor.createdAt`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`updated_at` AS `order_agreements.contractor.updatedAt`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`deleted_at` AS `order_agreements.contractor.deletedAt`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`archived_at` AS `order_agreements.contractor.archivedAt`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`payment_type_id` AS `order_agreements.contractor.paymentTypeId`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`address_id` AS `order_agreements.contractor.addressId`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`payment_type_id` AS `order_agreements.contractor.PaymentTypeId`,
    `order_agreements->contractor`.`address_id` AS `order_agreements.contractor.AddressId`
FROM
    `orders` AS `Order`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` AS `user`
ON
    `Order`.`user_id` = `user`.`id` AND(`user`.`deleted_at` IS NULL)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `companies` AS `company`
ON
    `Order`.`company_id` = `company`.`id` AND(`company`.`deleted_at` IS NULL)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `inspections` AS `inspection`
ON
    `Order`.`id` = `inspection`.`order_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `photo_documentations` AS `inspection->photo_documentation`
ON
    `inspection`.`id` = `inspection->photo_documentation`.`inspection_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `properties` AS `property`
ON
    `Order`.`id` = `property`.`order_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `addresses` AS `property->address`
ON
    `property`.`address_id` = `property->address`.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN(
        `selected_tasks` AS `tasks->SelectedTask`
    INNER JOIN `tasks` AS `tasks`
    ON
        `tasks`.`id` = `tasks->SelectedTask`.`task_id`
    )
ON
    `Order`.`id` = `tasks->SelectedTask`.`order_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `order_agreements` AS `order_agreements`
ON
    `Order`.`id` = `order_agreements`.`order_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `companies` AS `order_agreements->client`
ON
    `order_agreements`.`client_id` = `order_agreements->client`.`id` AND(
        `order_agreements->client`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
    )
LEFT OUTER JOIN `companies` AS `order_agreements->contractor`
ON
    `order_agreements`.`contractor_id` = `order_agreements->contractor`.`id` AND(
        `order_agreements->contractor`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
    )
WHERE
    (
        `Order`.`user_id` = 396 OR `Order`.`company_id` = 57 OR `Order`.`id` IN(
            1,
            2,
            3,
            ... #more IDs here
        )
    )
ORDER BY
    `Order`.`id`
DESC
LIMIT 4270, 10;
```

And lastly this is returned:

```
meta: {totalRows: 4277, totalPages: 428},
orders:
  0: {id: 20714, service: "***", ***: "***", status: "in_progress",…},
  1: {id: 20715, service: "***", ***: "***", status: "in_progress",…},
  2: {id: 20716, service: "***", ***: "***", status: "in_progress",…},
  3: {id: 20735, service: "***", ***: "***", status: "in_progress",…},
  4: {id: 20751, service: "***", ***: "***", status: "in_progress",…},
  5: {id: 20767, service: "***", ***: "***", status: "in_progress",…},
  6: {id: 20768, service: "***", ***: "***", status: "paused",…},
  7: {id: 20782, service: "***", ***: "***", status: "in_progress",…},
  8: {id: 20793, service: "***", ***: "***", status: "in_progress",…},
  9: {id: 20794, service: "***", ***: "***", status: "in_progress",…}
```

## Edit

Workaround-2: I first count the over all and get the  limited  result without includes and then create another where clause including previous result like:

```
    findObject.where = {
      id: { [Op.in]: orders.map((order) => order.id) }
    }
    findObject.offset = undefined
    findObject.limit = undefined
```

And it is much faster than getting everything and slicing.